# What is the cheapest way to email someone whenever a button is pressed or a switch is closed?

Tags: arduino, ethernet, low-power

I would like to be notified somewhere else on the internet every time my door opens at home. If I do this with a magnetic switch, I realize that this is an event that would probably stay under 0.3 Hz. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking arduino with an ethernet shield is a little overkill. And is there a way to make it wireless? Say with a "wireless doorbell" type circuit?

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest way is to wire a switch on your door directly to your PC, shorting a key on the keyboard. The rest is 'free' programming. 20m of wire and a decent momentary push-button switch cost about $5 in Canada.

Comment: Or the hi-tech version putting a USB HID device on the switch that acts like a keyboard.

Comment: 0.3 Hz - that's an awfully large amount of "traffic". 540 open/close cycles per hour :-).

Comment: I think he was referring to the time the event is active, about 3 seconds :)

Comment: ...assuming zero cost for a PC

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest wireless way would be to use some kind of 433MHz board and a TI Launchpad. A 433MHz transceiver cost about 5€ (you need 2), and the launchpad costs exactly 4.30$. You need to program the Launchpad in C, doesn't know if that will be a problem for you.
Another thing you could try is to connect a GSM modem to your Launchpad and let it send you an SMS/Giving you a call every time the door get opened, but this wouldn't be that cheap since you would have to pay for the texts or calls. Old GSM modems are around 10-15€ on ebay if you are lucky.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an Arduino with an Ethernet Shield, but you do need a controller with an Ethernet connectivity if you don't want to delegate any of the "heavy lifting" to a PC. You can get the same level of functionality and Arduino compatibility from a [Nanode](http://wickeddevice.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=26&products_id=102) - which incorporates a Microchip ENC28J60 ethernet controller and an ATMega328 onto a single board for just under $40 USD. Disclaimer: I sell the Nanode, so I am not totally unbiased in this regard, but I think this is your cheapest route that doesn't require a PC in the loop.